# Parametric equation for intersection of $\rho=2$ and $r=2\cos(\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the (top) intersection of $\rho=2$ and $r=2\cos(\theta)$.

Here's what I have in mind:

$x=r\cos(\theta) =2\cos^2 (\theta)$

$y=r \sin (\theta)=2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)$

$z=\sqrt{4-r^2}=2|\sin (\theta)|$

With $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Is this correct and is the absolute value necessary because it makes my life much harder when I try to compute a line integral along this  closed curve.

Also I'm interested in other parameterizations one can come up with.

The second part of the question is to compute the line integral of the closed region.

The force is $\langle xz,yz,z^2 \rangle$. And  I am considering using stokes for the second part but can't figure out a surface/how to write the surface in parametric form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\rho=2$ is the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $r=2\cos\theta$ is the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$, i.e., $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. So you can parametrize the curve $C$ as follows
\begin{cases}
x=1+\cos\theta\\
y=\sin\theta\\
z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{4-(1+\cos\theta)^2-\sin^2\theta}
\end{cases}
with $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$.

Now, for the surface $S$, use parameters $x$ and $y$:
\begin{cases}
x=x\\
y=y\\
z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}
\end{cases}
with $(x,y)\in D =\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le2x\}$.

You can now compute the integral:
$$
\oint_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_S\nabla\times \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}= \iint_D\nabla\times \vec{F}(x,y)\cdot \vec{r}_x\times \vec{r}_y\;dA
$$
I get 
$$
\vec{F}(x,y)\cdot \vec{r}_x\times \vec{r}_y = \pmatrix{-y\\x\\0}\cdot\pmatrix{\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\\\frac{y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\\1}=0
$$
Therefore the integral equals $0$.

Comment: Is my parameterization acceptable.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Notice the difference with mine: in yours $\theta$ ranges from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, in mine from $0$ to $2\pi$. Both are acceptable.